# Java output an xml from pojo class while appending additional object

Tags: java

I have a master entity that has 3 attributes . And i wish to return an xml  something like this

```
<masterentitiy>
    <complete>1</complete>
    <srcsize>2</srcsize>
    <purl lang="en" format="for">url</purl>
</masterentitiy>
```

MasterEntity pojo

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name="masterentitiy")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MasterResponse implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement
    private boolean complete;

    @XmlElement
    private Long srcsize;

    @XmlElement
    private List<Change> ch;
}
```

2 attributes complete,srcsize are getting populated using some api like this .

```
MasterResponse masterResponse= getRapiDataforCidAndJobCode(cid,jobCode);
```

And the Pojo class for  Change is

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Change implements Serializable {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String f;
            
    @XmlElement(name="purl")
    private String url;
            
    @XmlAttribute
    private String l;           
}
```

when i am creating a sample list and adding to the masterresponse it is giving error that Change dont exits

```
Change sub = new Change() ;
sub.setUrl("url");
sub.setLang("en");
sub.setFormat("for");
List<Change> com = new ArrayList<>();
com.add(sub);
                
masterResponse.setSubtitles(com);
```

Error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol: method setUrl(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Looks like you are using Lombok's `@Setter` to generate the setters for your fields. Are you sure the Lombok compiler plugin is configured correctly? Is other Lombok-generated code usable?

Comment: yeah using lombok only,  its working fine for others . If this code is correct may be i can try some other version .

Comment: it worked , after and adding again . thanks .